# What "settlement" is Jayne referring to?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), Mal, Zoe and Jayne emerge from the Serenity in full suits, armed.
Zoe reads a handheld scanner to capture beacon's signal:

> Malcolm: Gravity's Earthnorm.
>
> Zoe: O2 levels check, pressure...If anything's wrong the
> scanner's not reading it.
>
> Jayne: This ain't no little **settlement**.

What "settlement" is Jayne referring to ?

Comment: They were under the impression that Miranda was a small settlement due to the fact no one had heard of it. Jayne was surprised it was a large colony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miranda was supposedly a small settlement that went bad due to a "terraforming event" near the start of the Unification War. Jayne's comment about it *not* being a settlement (in the film) seems to hark back to an earlier version of the script. The line about it having 'settlements' was removed and replaced with a couple of different lines about a small number of 'settlers', but they evidently kept his line untouched.

> "*O brave new world, that has such people in it.*" It's called Blackrock now because it's not livable. Before, though, when it was new, **when they were talking about flying in the first settlements, they'd named it "Miranda."**
>
> <sub><sup>Serenity: Original Screenplay</sup></sub>

Jayne is noting that this isn't a small settlement, it's in fact a major colony with multiple advanced cities and, potentially, millions of dead people, something that should be very much in the awareness of folks like him.